# Does the Torah teach, that mountains have an extension below the mountain’s base?

Tags: torah-study, hebrew

Job 28:9 “They put their hand to the flinty rock,and overturn mountains by the roots מִשֹּׁ֣רֶשׁ.

the word מִשֹּׁ֣רֶשׁ is used literally for a root of tree or shrub,as in Jeremiah 17:8

Does the Torah, as in Job 28:9, teach that mountains have an extension below the mountain’s base, which is scientifically correct?

Comment: The text seems to be speaking of a foundation or a continuation of the mountain into the earth. The Metzudat David writes ומהפך את ההרים מן השורש בסבת הרוח הנסגר בבטן הארץ

Answer (score 1):

Sure looks like it. To be fair, I don't think realizing mountains continue underground is some kind of advanced knowledge. I assume everyone who lived around mountains realized that, especially in an agrarian society.